# Combobox itemtemplate and string or comboboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Need a small fix with comboboxitems in wpf. I want to show the comboboxitems or  in the comboxbox (textblock) with an image beside. I couldn't get it done. Can someone help me with the fix please?

Thanks in advance

```
   <ComboBox Name="avilibity" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="/resources/icon.png" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="2" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <sys:String>Available</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Offline</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Away</sys:String>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Problem is that the Grid Column index is 0 based - means Image shold have Grid.Column = "0", TextBlock = "1".

Should it be allways the same image? Consider using of user-defined object as property with binding. Thus you can have individual icons.

May be one of the gurus here can provide XAML-only example... i can imagine only with code behind...

Here two possible solutions:

Code behind in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListImageWithText
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private List<ImageWithText> _objectlist;


    public List<ImageWithText> ObjectList
    {
        get
        {
            return _objectlist;
        }

        set
        {
            _objectlist = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ObjectList");
        }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ImageWithText iwt;
        this._objectlist = new List<ImageWithText>();

        iwt = new ImageWithText();
        iwt.Image = "App.ico";
        iwt.Text = "Away";
        this._objectlist.Add(iwt);

        iwt = new ImageWithText();
        iwt.Image = "App.ico";
        iwt.Text = "Available";
        this._objectlist.Add(iwt);

        iwt = new ImageWithText();
        iwt.Image = "App.ico";
        iwt.Text = "Offline";
        this._objectlist.Add(iwt);
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ObjectList");
    }
}

public class ImageWithText
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
}
```

Define small class with two public properties, present list of those objects as property and use binding in XAML

```
    <ComboBox Name="avilibity"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}">


        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
```

The simplest way with XAML repetitions - is use of ComboBox Items, i do not preffer this path...

```
    <ComboBox Name="avilibity"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Grid.Column="1">

        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="App.ico" ></Image>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" >Available</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ComboBoxItem>

        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="App.ico" ></Image>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" >Offline</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ComboBoxItem>

        <ComboBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="App.ico" ></Image>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" >Away</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code:
1. Row & Column are start with index 0;
2. TextBlock need to set the Text Property, so that it can display.

If you just want to display the same icon,
this code will gonna work(this can fix your perblom):

```
<ComboBox Name="avilibity" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/resources/icon.png" ></Image>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <sys:String>Available</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Offline</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Away</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

But as I saw, there are three kind of state of the items.
Maybe you want to change the image when different item display.

Here is my solution:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="avilibity" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <sys:String>Available</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Offline</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Away</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

ImageSourceConverter:

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/resources/" + value + ".png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```